# Items in JFrame not shown

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I hava a function to add Elements to a Jframe. But only the last InputField as well as the Button are shown. How can i show all elements including the table that i create?

```
   public TablePrototype()
   {
       frm = new JFrame("Employee Management System");
       frm.setSize(1000, 1000);

       //List with employee
       Employee emp1 = new Employee("John", "Doe", 1, "Male", "30.03.1997", "info@john-doe.com","3334567888","Graz, Südtirolerplatz 125");
       Employee emp2 = new Employee("Martha", "Zwicker", 2, "Female", "28.06.1965", "info@email.com","3362341234","Graz, Andreas Hofer Platz 180");
       Employee emp3 = new Employee("Engelbert", "Strauss", 3, "Male", "30.06.1987", "strauss@engelbert.com","3362651294","Graz, Wagner Biro Straße 11");

       employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
       employeeList.add(emp1);
       employeeList.add(emp2);
       employeeList.add(emp3);

       EmployeeTable model = new EmployeeTable(employeeList);
       table = new JTable(model);
        inputfield1 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield1.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield2 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield2.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield3 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield3.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield4 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield4.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield5 =  new JTextField(250);
       inputfield5.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield6 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield6.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield7 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield7.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       inputfield8 = new JTextField(250);
       inputfield8.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
       frm.add(table);
       frm.add(new JLabel("First Name"));
       frm.add(inputfield1);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Last Name"));
       frm.add(inputfield2);
       frm.add(new JLabel("ID number"));
       frm.add(inputfield3);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Gender"));
       frm.add(inputfield4);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Date of birth"));
       frm.add(inputfield5);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Email"));
       frm.add(inputfield6);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Phone"));
       frm.add(inputfield7);
       frm.add(new JLabel("Address"));
       frm.add(inputfield8);

       addButton = new JButton("Add");
       addButton.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
       addButton.setActionCommand(SAVE);
       addButton.addActionListener(this);

       frm.add(addButton);

       frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frm.setLayout(null);
       frm.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
       frm.setVisible(true);
   }
```

I want to add the table to the JFrame than always a textfield with label above and at last the button.

Comment: What layout do you want to use for your JFrame? The default one is a BorderLayout, which doesn't support adding elements the way you're doing it.

Comment: I use a FlowLayout with frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout())

Comment: Youre setting your layout to `null` in `frm.setLayout(null);`

Comment: You might like the gridbag layout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: All the input fields have the same position. Why is it a surprise that only one displays? **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will show you the correct way to create a Swing GUI.  You don't add Swing components to a JFrame.  You add Swing components to a JPanel and add the JPanel to a JFrame.  You use a GridBagLayout to create a form with JLabels and JTextFields.  Your employee JTable will take up so much JFrame space that you will probably have to use JDialogs to create, update, and delete employee records.